# Running Script from

Tags: c#, backgroundworker

I have an application that contains a rich text box in my main window of my GUI. My code for my main GUI is my "Main.cs" file. I have written a test script in my "TestScripts.cs" file. I also have a `BackgroundWorker` on my main GUI.

My question is how do I execute the test script in the `BackgroundWorker` of my "Main.cs" code? This code is set to update the rich text box on the main GUI.

I presumed it would be something like:

```
private void backgroundWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
   TestScripts.Test1();  // Find the specific script in my "TestScripts" code and execute in the background worker
}
```

However, I haven't figured out how to access the specific test script in my background code. In other words I can get to `TestScripts` but not `TestScripts.Test1();`.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Please post the code for TestScripts.cs, as the problem most likely lies there.

Comment: Couple things; what you have there is almost certainly not a 'script', and we'll need to see the definition of `TestScripts` and its `Test1()` method. You possibly need to instantiate an instance of it

Answer (score 1):

If I may suggest, you don't need a secondary script really; I feel it's a bit un-needed is all. Rather you can do something like:

```
richTextBox1.Invoke(new Action(() => { richTextBox1.Text += "New Text Here From Worker!"; }));
```

You can even put it in a void if you want to call it that way:

```
public void UpdateText(string text){
richTextBox1.Invoke(new Action(() => { richTextBox1.Text += text; }));
```

}

Then call it...

```
UpdateText("Hey New text!");
```

I'm sorry if this didn't help you, I thought I would suggest it though. Good luck man!